# What do the engine annotations 0.53/24 mean?

Tags: engines, fritz

I am anaylizing my games with Fritz to get better, but there is an annotation in the analysis that I do not fully understand. Here is an example:

[image: Annotation example]

What do **0.53/21** and **-0.25/24** mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The score **0.53/21** means the chess engine evaluates the position after **6... Ng8-f6** at **0.53** pawns (or 53 centipawns) in **White's favour** after completing a search depth of **21** ply (or half-moves). It means White has a slight advantage.

Similarly **-0.25/24** means the engine evaluates the position after **6... e7-e6** as **0.25** pawns (or 25 centipawns) in **Black's favour** after a search depth of 24 half-moves.

Comment: What is the usefullness in knowing the search depth? Is it relevant for the reliability of the evaluation score?

Comment: @MartijnBurger If you could choose between an engine that looked 5 moves ahead and another that looked 20 moves ahead, regardless of whether they gave the same evaluation or not, in which engine's evaluation would you be more confident?

Comment: @MartijnBurger basically high depth is always good. An engine could evaluate a position at 0.53/21 *and* also evaluate the position as -3.3/50. The latter evaluation, being at much higher depth (i.e. the engine needs to think longer to search that far ahead), should also be more accurate.